# Domain from Microsoft hosted by azure

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress, azure, microsoft

I like to build websites using WordPress. I am self-taught and can generally sort out nameservers to point to a domain. You will guess from my question that I am no expert!

I have just build a website using WordPress in azure but it has the name `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`.

`mywebsite.example` was bought from Microsoft.

Is there a way of changing from `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net` to `mywebsite.example`?

Comment: Do you have access to edit the DNS records for mywebsite.azurewebsites.net?  If so, you could point the DNS records to mydomain.com.

Comment: @Trebor it is going to be more complicated than that.   In addition to DNS there will be: Azure domain mapping configurations (like virtual hosts), SSL certificates to obtain, and WordPress settings to tweak.  Here is a whole article devoted to the topic: https://www.greginks.com/cloud/custom-domain-mapping-for-wordpress-in-azure-web-app/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, thanks.  I hadn't thought that far ahead.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It looks less complicated than the one on azure so I’ll give it a try!

Comment: When you say `mywebsite.example` was bought from Microsoft, do you mean that you purchased it through the "Custom Domains" blade of the Web App, or through some other means?